# Why is the whole site jumping when using affix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a navbar and a subnav under a Carousel. And my subnav should be fixed after getting there. It is fixed but content is jumping. 
if i only would use a container above i would already have found a solution but it don't work for me, so its still jumping..
I already saw some solutions but don't get it..
so what am i doing false?

https://jsfiddle.net/sdkpj9f3/

```css
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#myCarousel {
  padding: 0px;
}
.subnav {
  margin: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: rgba(85, 93, 106, 0.7);
  border-style: none;
}
.subnav.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.subNav-item:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgba(111, 131, 158, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top navtop">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navtop">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!--LOGO-->
      <a href="index.html" class="">
        <img src="images/logos/RULogo.png" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--NAV START-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class=""><a href="">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class=""><a href="">Shop</a>
        </li>
        <li class=""><a href="">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class=""><a href="contact.html">About & Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--NAV END-->
  </nav>

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="images/picture3.jpg" alt="img1">
        <div class="carousel-caption white-on-white">
          <h1>Welcome</h1>
          <h2>kjlkjkl</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="contact.html" class="no-link">
          <img src="images/picture1.jpg" alt="img1">
          <div class="carousel-caption white-on-white">
            <h1>Who?</h1>
        </a>
        <h2>Developers</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

  </div>
  <!--SlideShow END-->

  <!--SubNav-->

  <nav class="navbar subnav" role="navigation">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse collapse-buttons">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="subNav-item"><a href="#">something</a>
        </li>
        <li class="subNav-item"><a href="">something</a>
        </li>
        <li class="subNav-item"><a href="">something</a>
        </li>
        <li class="subNav-item"><a href="">something</a>
        </li>
        <li class="subNav-item"><a href="#">something</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!--END SUbnav-->


  <div id="Code" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="well well-lg">
          <p>this picture has blablablablabalbalb</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="well well-lg">
          <p>this picture has blablablablabalbalb</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Container (Portfolio Section) -->
  <div id="portfolio" class="container-fluid text-center">
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
    <br>
    <h4>What we have created</h4>
    <div class="row text-center slideanim">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="images/picture1.jpg" alt="Paris" width="400" height="300">
          <p><strong>bla blaa</strong>
          </p>
          <p>blablablabll lbalabl lab lab</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="images/picture2.jpg" alt="New York" width="400" height="300">
          <p><strong>blablabla</strong>
          </p>
          <p>blablabalbalbala</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="images/picture3.jpg" alt="San Francisco" width="400" height="300">
          <p><strong>blablabalbal</strong>
          </p>
          <p>bla, blabla bla ba</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>


    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var h = $('.navtop').height();
      var h2 = $('#myCarousel').height();
      var h3 = h + h2;
      $('.subnav').affix({
        offset: {
          top: 1200
        }
      });
    </script>

    <body>

</html>
```

Comment: add your code like jsfiddle

Comment: What do you mean *jumping*?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example in your question, the code provided in its current form doesn't appear to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: yes im working on a jsfiddle pls wait a moment

Comment: how do i use fiddle ? i don't get it :( this community is so aggressiv instant -1 instead of help

Comment: @Ams1 no one can help you if you don't provide the proper resources for them to help you. Instead of complaining about people giving you a -1, perhaps you should take it as an indication that your question is not well formed, and you need to improve it.

Comment: @AR7 i want to improve it! see my question above pls... i have my jsfiddle but don't know how to get it here see: https://jsfiddle.net/sdkpj9f3/

Comment: @Ams1 all you need to do is include the link at the beginning of your question so it's more visible to people. Now what you need to do is express,: what you mean by jumping, how to make the page jump, and what your overall goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when the site jumps from affix, it's because the header becomes position fixed and leaves the layout and is position on top of the content itself. The rest of the site "jumps" up the height of the header.

One thing you can do is wrap your navbar in a wrapper and give the navbar wrapper the height of the nav.

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">  
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top navtop">
        <!-- the rest of your nav code is here -->
    </nav>
</div>
```

and in css

```
.navbar-wrapper { height:60px; } /* or whatever the height of the nav is */
```

You can find the height of your nav by using the browser inspector or by guessing until the jump disappears.

Here is your [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdkpj9f3/1/), cleaned up a bit so it works.

Comment: is this just for nav or could i do this with a other element ?

Comment: @Ams1 you can do this with whatever element you are affixing.  I also cleaned up your JSfiddle a little and put my fix in it, so you can see the jumping stops.

Comment: Nice you realy helped me out :)) thanks alot i appriciate that. Because i don't get it when everyone starts hatting about something i don't know how to fix :( i mean which guy would ask something when he is already a pro... im hear to improve my skills and the most guys in this community are like oh god he is dump af so i'll -1 him because he isn't at my lvl...

Comment: @Ams1 I hate it too.  Surely not everyone is a "master stack overflow user"...  Anyways, if my answer did indeed solve your problem, please mark the answer as correct / accepted :)

Comment: it did! thanks alot again!
But does it work responsive ?
Im getting a big gap if i make the page smaller

Comment: @Ams1 You need to add a media query then, one that adjusts for the height of the wrapper wherever it changes.

Comment: okay :/, i hoped their is another way then typing it for every size, but thx for the awnser anyway :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133012/discussion-between-jacob-raccuia-and-ams1).